# Child action/partial view is not being rendered when called in asp.net mvc 2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm sure it's something small (or maybe big), but my child action isn't working. I have a childaction that populates a List with year values. This list is to be displayed via a partial control. I see the respective pieces of code executed when I step through the code, yet nothing renders on the page.

Child Action:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetYearList()
    {
        return PartialView(_FormService.getYears());
    }
```

Call used in parent view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    Select Year: <% Html.Action("GetYearList"); %>
```

Partial View code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<SelectListItem>>" %>

<% if (Model != null)
   { %>
        <% Html.DropDownList("Year", Model, "Select  Year"); %>
<% } else { %>
    <p> No Years Found </p>
<% }  %>
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? I could just render the partial view directly, but I'm really  trying to figure out how the ChildActions work so I use them in the future should that logic be more complicated.

**edit 1**

Silly semantics. Had to change my GetYearList partial view to:

```
    <%= Html.DropDownList("Year", Model, "Select 1099 Year") %>
```

instead of

```
<% Html.DropDownList("Year", Model, "Select  Year"); %>
```

Same sort of thing on parent view as Darin stated:

```
change  Select Year: <% Html.Action("GetYearList"); %>

to <%= Html.Action("Get1099YearList") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the child action but doing nothing to render it to the output:

```
<% Html.Action("GetYearList"); %>
```

should become:

```
<%= Html.Action("GetYearList") %>
```

or if you prefer:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("GetYearList"); %>
```

And their Razor equivalents for those who might be interested:

```
@Html.Action("GetYearList")
@{Html.RenderAction("GetYearList");}
```

Comment: I have adjusted the parent view call to: <%= Html.Action("GetYearList") %>  The drop down still never renders; however, if I step through the code, both the child action and the partial view get called. I just have no idea where the results end up as they don't end up on the page.

Comment: @Json, I don't know what to say. `<%= Html.Action("GetYearList") %>` should work. You may also checkout the following article from Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: Does it matter that my partial view and child action have the same names? Also, that article is the one I've been using as my guide. Thanks for the link though. I'll keep hacking away at it.

Comment: @Jason, no this doesn't matter. It's the standard convention. An action called GetYearList will look for `GetYearList.ascx` partial if not specified otherwise. Are you using AJAX?

Comment: No, I'm not making any ajax/jquery/javascript type calls here. It's straight forward mvc 2 html helper calling the child action. It's a bit maddening because I can step through the code on debug, see the childaction called, see the partial view called and supposedly processed, and then see the rest of the view process. It's like the Partial View is not returning anything despite that I 1) Know it's called, 2) Know it ought to be generating some html even if only a minimal amount.

Comment: Had to make a similar change to the parent & partial views. Thanks for your input!